# Creating List in Sharepoint takes ages

Tags: list, sharepoint, templates, exception, sharepoint-2010

I try to clear a very big list in Sharepoint. Because of Sharepoints slow deleting-mechanism I decided to save a template (without data) from that list, delete that list and then create a new list from that template. The code of that is below:

```
public static void TruncateList(SPList list)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
      using (SPSite site = new SPSite(list.ParentWeb.Site.ID))
      {
         using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
         {            
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
               SPList listCopy = web.Lists[list.ID];
               string title = listCopy.Title;
               string description = listCopy.Description;
               string backupName = string.Format("BACKUP_{0}", title);

               // Delete old Template if exists:
               SPList gallery = web.Lists["List Template Gallery"];
               foreach (SPListItem item in gallery.Items)
               {
                  if (item.Title == backupName)
                  {
                     item.Delete();
                     break;
                  }
               }

               // Save Template:
               listCopy.SaveAsTemplate(backupName, backupName, string.Empty, false);

               // Load Template:
               SPListTemplate template = web.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web)[backupName];
               template = web.ListTemplates[backupName];

               // Delete List:
               listCopy.Delete();   

               // Add empty List from Template:   [HANGS HERE!]                                                        
               web.Lists.Add(title, description, template);

               web.Update();
               web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
         }
         );
        }
    }
}
```

Saving the template works fine as well as deleting the original list (listCopy.Delete()) which takes a while

But when trying to create that List again (web.Lists.Add) the server got stuck until it gets a Timeout-Exception after some minutes.

Useful to mention: This is my developer machine. Noone but me is accessing that web/List

Comment: Anything interesting in your ULS logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself:

The problem was that I was using that list ("list") as a parameter. I changed it to just send the ID of that list to that method and use

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
```

inside. Now it works.